# Splitting string into numbers by commas and then printing ends up skipping 1 y-value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input, output

This code was made to take x and y as input, split the strings by the commas, convert them to an integer, and then print out the string.

```
<body>
    x: <input id="xv"> <br/>
    y: <input id="yv">
    <br/>
    <div id="results">
    <button onclick="action()">Go</button>
    </div>

    <script>

        // javascript
        var action = function(){

            // separate by commas and place into array
            var xvs = document.getElementById("xv").value.split(",");
            var yvs = document.getElementById("yv").value.split(",");

            // convert to an integer
            for(var i=0, j=xvs.length; i<j; i++){
                xvs[i] = parseInt(xvs[i]);
                yvs[i] = parseInt(yvs[i]);
            }

            // print out results
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xvs + "<br/>" + yvs;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

You would expect it to print out an identical copy of the input. However, instead, I get this result:

```
Input:
62,64,64,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,68,69,69 
62,63,63,64,66,65,64,67,67,63,64,68,65,66,66,65,68,68.69,70 

Output:
62,64,64,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,68,69,69
62,63,63,64,66,65,64,67,67,63,64,68,65,66,66,65,68,68,70,NaN
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zs65x2e3/

Note that without putting it into an individual `<script>` tag the code does not work, as `action()` is considered `undefined`.

Comment: Is that the input you used? because it has an error in it. Period instead of a comma in second line of input

Comment: Oh, oops. I was copying and pasting that faulty input the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your input,

Old:

```
62,64,64,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,68,69,69 
62,63,63,64,66,65,64,67,67,63,64,68,65,66,66,65,68,68.69,70
```

Fixed:

```
62,64,64,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,68,69,69 
62,63,63,64,66,65,64,67,67,63,64,68,65,66,66,65,68,68,69,70
```

You had a period instead of a comma.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not because of the period. The looping has a problem.
You are running the loop on the length of the x input. If the y input has lesser inputs than x inputs then you will get NaN for the remaining iterations for y. 
In your sample input the period caused the length of the inputs to be less than 1 hence you got 1 NaN at the end.

Comment: The error is actually because of the period. You are not meant to input different amounts of x and y values - because of the period, it thought it was one number, reducing the number of y values.